# Is it possible to move photos on iPhone to external storage?

Tags: iphone, storage

I'm going on vacation soon (The Black Forest) and I'm planning to take a lot of Hi-Res photos and videos.

However, since it is a vacation, I prefer to stay away from my laptop (otherwise, I would spend time coding or checking work's email).

Is it possible to move the photos and videos on iPhone to external storage, whether it is SSD or SD card for example?

Comment: Have you considered moving all your photos to your Mac's Photo Library before going on the trip?

Comment: Have a look at: [Leef iBridge Mobile Memory](http://www.leefco.com/ibridge)

Answer (score 1):

To get it on to an external drive, your photos need to get to a computer first (because an external drive can not be plugged into an iPhone).

To get the photos to a Mac, you can use a standard iPhone to USB lightning cable to plug your phone into the computer. Your Mac will normally pop up asking to import the photos, accept this. (Windows computers might be capable of this, I am not sure.)

Or you can use iCloud Drive for any computer. On your phone, turn on iCloud Photo Library in settings. When your photos are uploaded to the cloud, go to iCloud.com on your computer. Open the photos web-app, select your desired photos, and at the top, you should see some buttons to import the photos to your computer.

Once the photos are on your laptop, you can move them to your desired external drive.

Comment: You said, "_To get it on to an external drive, your photos need to get to a computer first (because an external drive can not be plugged into an iPhone)._" and this is not necessarily true, depends on which iPhone you have. As an example, the [Leef iBridge Mobile Memory](http://www.leefco.com/ibridge) works with iPhone SE, iPhone 6s/6s Plus, iPhone 6/6 Plus, and iPhone 5/5s/5c running iOS 8 or iOS 9, without a computer.

Comment: I was unaware of this, as most users probably are. Thank you for pointing this out. I will leave my answer as-is just because most people have a computer, and most people do not want to buy an extra commodity. However, if you think your point is relevant, then I suggest you post it as an answer